# Azure data factory Dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a DelimitedText ADF dataset. It is pipe delimited. When I use this as a source in copy data activity in a pipeline and write the file data to a SQL database table, blank values are loaded as NULL.

How can I avoid this? I want blank values to read as blank values and write into database table as blank values.

I tried keeping NULL value as blank and "treatEmptyAsNull": false in dataset json; both didnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can using data flow derivedcolumn expression to achieve that.

Comment: I want to use only 'Copy Data" activity. Anyways I got the solution: I have given expression concat('') for NULL value property in the dataset

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the solutions. We can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and set NULL value property with `''`, it works:
[image]

Result comparation:

[image]

I tested expression `concat('')`,  it also works.

Hope this helps.